# Eclipse IDE not opening

Tags: eclipse, fedora

OS - Fedora 13. I have tried answers from other similar questions. I have deleted my .metadata folder. Tried opening from command line with the -clean option, however, it just gets stuck, and does not open. I do not get any error messages.

Any pointers?

Comment: There is no output even when opening from command line? Have you tried downloading a fresh Eclipse? Even if you prefer to keep your current installation, this might help narrowing down the problem.

Comment: Launch on the command line with -console -consolelog to see more details about what's going on.  Include those details in your question.

Comment: I redownloaded my workspace from repos. and eclipse opened fine. Thanks guys.